# Post your answer button is disabled why

Tags: support, questions, answers, design, closed-questions

why i am not able to post my answers to a question

**Post Your Answer** button is disabled

I tried answering a java question and i am not able to post any answer.The **Post Your Answer** button is disabled.Why?

Comment: Give the link to the question ( maybe the question  has been closed ) Try reloading the page and try answering again ( copy your answer first ).

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear - I was searching for exactly this and also found the answer to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When questions are flagged and the flag is approved, then you will become unable to answer them. Even if the question was not closed when you were typing an answer, if the question becomes closed or marked as duplicate, then you will no longer be able to post an answer to it.

Quoting from SO [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> Questions that need additional work or that 
>   [are not a good fit for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) may be put on hold by experienced community members. **While
>   questions are on hold, they cannot be answered**, but can be edited to
>   make them eligible for reopening.

There is also the chance of [user ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) as explained in this link.

So as you said that the question was marked duplicate, that is the reason you were unable to answer it. It is done so that users do not keep posting answers when there is already an answer to it.

Comment: I spent a lot of time to write an answer for somebody just to get a grayed out button. It was marked as possible duplicate which I really don't agree it's a duplicate of the linked post. So I had to erase half of what I wrote just to fit it in a comment. Seems like too much of a hassle to answer questions for people

Comment: I have run into the same thing a couple of times. You start answering a question, and before you submit it someone comes along and marks it as duplicate/too vague or something else, leaving you with the result of 5-10 minutes of work, which just goes down the drain. This is incredible annoying, and in my opinion it fosters a behavior where, if someone intent to answer a question, he should first submit a placeholder, and then produce the actual answer to avoid having to throw away your work.

Comment: I think some people are happy to answer these questions, I think they really should be allowed to answer, even though they are duplicates etc.